# Android sockets not reveving data from server

Tags: python, android, sockets

I am trying to send data from python server to android client but it is not accepting any data from the server. but it is showing that it is connected with the server. i cant recognize any error.

here is my client code in android java.

```
package com.example.socketinput;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Thread Thread1 = null;
    String SERVER_IP="192.168.1.6";
    int SERVER_PORT=9857;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Thread1 = new Thread(new Thread1());
        Thread1.start();
    }
    private PrintWriter output;
    private BufferedReader input;
    class Thread1 implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            Socket socket;
            try {
                socket = new Socket(SERVER_IP, SERVER_PORT);
                output = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
                input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Log.i("Server", "Connected");
                    }
                });
                new Thread(new Thread2()).start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.i("Server", "Error in thread 1");
            }
        }
    }
    class Thread2 implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    final String message = input.readLine();
                    if (message != null) {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Log.i("Server", message);
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        Thread1 = new Thread(new Thread1());
                        Thread1.start();
                        return;
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.i("Server", "Error in thread 2");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

here is my python server code .

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

# In[1]:


import socket


# In[2]:
socket.gethostname()

s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('', 9857))
s.listen(5)


# In[ ]:


while True:
    clientsocket, address = s.accept()
    print(f"connection from {address} has been established!")
    clientsocket.send(bytes("welcome to the server!","utf-8"))

    while True:
        msg=input()
        clientsocket.send(bytes(msg,"utf-8"))
```

android manifent file is-:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.socketinput">
    <uses-permission android:name = "android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name = "android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Note-Android app and python code is connected on same server.

[image]

Comment: What messages are you seeing on both the server and client side? Please post screenshots or copy paste the output.

Comment: You do not have to use runOnUiThread to call Log.i.

Comment: check now i have pasted screenshot of the outputs

Answer (score 0):

In this code:

> s.bind(('', 9857))

You should also pass the host.

> s.bind(('192.168.1.6', 9857))

Comment: What message you are getting on the client side?

Answer (score 0):

`final String message = input.readLine();` wait until get '\n'

You need to `clientsocket.send(bytes("\n"))` when you want to stop sending.

```
while True:
    clientsocket, address = s.accept()
    print(f"connection from {address} has been established!")
    clientsocket.send(bytes("welcome to the server!\n","utf-8"))
```

Comment: Not working. it is not receiving any data from server.

Comment: not even  clientsocket.send(bytes("welcome to the server!","utf-8"))

Comment: it is only showing print(f"connection from {address} has been established!")

Comment: @kartikchauhan Then you need to send msg by decode, and at client encode, then see what you receive [python server](https://www.journaldev.com/15906/python-socket-programming-server-client)

Comment: And how can i do that?

Comment: @kartikchauhan Sorry at server encode, and at client decode. At server send like `clientsocket.send(msg.encode())`. At client `realine` will do that